# How to set custom file name when exporting html element to Png file using html2canvas in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I have a button in my application which exports the html div to png file. I did it using html2canvas library in jquery. The Problem here is when the file gets downloaded it downloads with default name "Download". I need to download with customized name. I have provided the code in the following. Any help is appreciated.

```
 $("#btnPng").click(function () {
                       html2canvas($("#pulledPopUp"), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                 theCanvas = canvas;
                    Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                                   }
            })

        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG` function does not provide an option to set file name. You can alternatively use `canvas.toDataURL()`, `<a>` element, with `download` attribute set to suggested file name; `.click()`

```
$("#btnPng").click(function () {
  html2canvas($("#pulledPopUp"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                  var url = canvas.toDataURL();
                  $("<a>", {
                    href: url,
                    download: "fileName"
                  })
                  .on("click", function() {$(this).remove()})
                  .appendTo("body")[0].click()
                }
  })
});
```

Comment: *The `Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG` function does not provide an option to set file name.* - it does, its header looks like: `saveAsPNG: function (canvas, width, height, fileName)`. So `Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas,canvas.width,canvas.height,"something.png");` should do the job.

Comment: @tevemadar do you have a documentation link that supports what you're saying?

Comment: @Gonzalingui it's easy: don't believe the readme.md, but look into the file itself. I assume hongru's is the original, https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image/network/members, https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image/blob/master/canvas2image.js#L299 in particular shows the real function header.